# Extract a JAR file, possibly with WINRAR on CL

Tags: java, command-line, jar, compression, winrar

I need to be able to extract jar files on the command line.

Piece of cake, you might say. Yes, except I need the extractor to rename same-named files.
To be specific, the Jar file has a file named:

```
classAX.class
```

and another named:

```
classax.class
```

in the same directory. I need it to extract them both, and preferably rename one:

```
classax (2).class
```

or something similar.

It must be able to do this without any user intervention.

Winrar has this capability, but when attempting to extract with unrar.exe, it says that the input file is not a valid RAR archive. (Though winrar has jar capabilities.)

Any way to force winrar to accept jars via command line, or perhaps another program?

Thanks,

~Kurt Nauck

Comment: A jar file is compressed in the zip format.  You could write your own extractor using java.util.zip package.

Comment: I can appreciate the accuracy of that. I'm looking for a slightly simpler and faster way of dealing with this minor problem.

Comment: The commad line tool `unrar` only supports `rar` format, while the WinRAR GUI can handle `zip` and several other formats as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7Zip command line util accomplishes this perfectly. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own programme in java, there is a Zip package that can deal with compressed files, an also you can deal with a rest of your needs